# tick labels number format excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some issues using custom number format in Excel. I want the numbers on the y-axis of a scatter graph to be number formatted, so 16 on the y axis is labelled as a grade G, 22 as a grade F, 28 as a grade E, and so on.  The following code works and formats my G and F correctly.

```
.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[=16]""G"";[=22]""F"";"
```

When I try to add any more formats in, say;

```
.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[=16]""G"";[=22]""F"";[=28]""E"";"
```

It no longer works. Is there a way around this problem?

NB: My y axis major unit is set to 6 and the axis minimum is set to 16, so all the grades I want lie on the tick markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Excel, unfortunately: a number format can contain up to 2 conditions.

This is confirmed [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm). I've looked around for the original Microsoft documentation for this but I can't find it. What I can say, however, is that all of the example format codes I've seen on Microsoft pages have up to two conditions, never more than two. I guess they were not expecting users to need more than two conditions.

One workaround: See [Jon Peltier's article on how to make arbitrary axes scales](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ArbitraryAxis.html). His example:

[image]